# how to get individual objects from NSUserdefaults Array

Tags: iphone

I am getting user details from .net web server.

I place all these in an array.

Now i need to place these array values in NSuserdefaults.

i try like this.

to store

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:resultData forKey:@"agentinfo"];
    [prefs synchronize];
```

to get

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs arrayForKey:@"agentinfo"]
```

i am getting details like this

```
 970,
    Aditya2,
    B,
    JNTU1,
    "Ram@gamil.com"
```

how can i get individual numbers 970,Aditya2...

Because i need to Assign them to label.

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringForKey` will always return `nil` if the object associated with the provided key is no string.  Try `arrayForKey` instead.

Comment: yes u r correct how can i assign getting value to array,means i need to get individual.I need to get Name,id like this

Comment: Then you probably need an NSDictionary instead of an nsarray. NSDictionary has method like getObjectForKey: or directly set your values in the preference plist

Answer (score 1):

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        yourArray = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"agentinfo"];
```

use this code for access the array.